# phpmyadmin 500 error iis (but phpinfo works just fine)

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, windows-10, iis-express

I'm using windows 10 width manually installed :
MySQL (5.7) and PHP (7.2.3) and a uncompressed phpadmin (v4.7.9) folder.

To validate PHP install i created a phpinfo page, which works.
But when i want to go to the phpadmin site and run index.php I get :

"Http Error 500, thats odd... the website can't display the page".

And sadly thats all, its not much information. 
There is no info beyond that,nothing usefull in IIS logs, or in Windows eventlogs.

If create a minimal  phpinfo    file in phpadmin folder then it just shows php server info (proving php works). I also checked that all required libs for phpadmin are configured in php.ini its ok.

So php works, mysql works, but the glue of phpadmin isnt working, how can validate phpadmin configuration ?.

Comment: Error 500 is always described more in error logs. Check phpinfo page for the path for where does it store error logs and check that file for more descriptive log

Comment: problem not with php, something wrong with phpadmin code. check logs

Comment: well in php.ini, i've set error_log to syslog, but nothing visible in windows eventlog in regard to phpadmin